# Setting A particular Day in a date

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using Calender Extender Control in the AjaxControlToolkit. There are basically 2 controls of date : `Start Date` and `End date` (both associated with calender extender). Based on start Date selected, I populate date in the end date field like adding no of months or days. But like I have been able to add months, but also wants to set a particular day of that month which I am unable to do.

Example:
Today date is `18 Dec 2012`. Something like 1st of every three months, So I add 3 months the month comes out to be `Feb 2013`. But I want to set Day `1st Feb 2013`. I am unable to do it. Kindly help.

Comment: Well how are you doing it, the date on which you add Months would have a different day  ! !

Comment: @V4Vendetta : For Adding No of months I am using like 


DueDate.Text = (DateTime.Parse(StartDate.Text).AddMonths(N)).ToShortDateString();



So i am able to add months, but unable to set particular day of the month

Comment: Well then try using `new DateTime(yr , mnt, yourday).ToShortDateString()`, here yr would be as in startdate and months as +N and then set your specific date

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set whatever day of month by add month.

```
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime after3MonthDate = todayDate.AddMonths(3);
//Set First Day of Month
after3MonthDate = new DateTime(after3MonthDate.Year, after3MonthDate.Month, 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

This code can be used for existing date time variable to set the day part to the first day of the month:

```
if(myDate.Day > 1)
{
    myDate = myDate.AddDays(-(myDate.Day - 1));
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: This might be less readable than the answer @Naresh Pansuriya, but it ensures that all of the `DateTime` information is transferred (as opposed to just the year and month) so I would argue this is a better solution than the accepted solution

Comment: Watch out for this, as you may encounter issues using it in conjunction with AddMonths. For example, if you AddMonth(1) to March 31st, it will be April 30th, not May 1st. So if you subtract 30 days (31 - 1) you will be back to March 31st, not April 1st.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
// Here is the simple wrapper method to get the first day of the month:
public DateTime FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
   return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
}

// Set the due date...
DueDate.Text = (FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime.Parse(StartDate.Text).AddMonths(N))).ToShortDateString();
```

You can also modify the wrapper method to get any day of the month:

```
public DateTime DayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime, int day)
{
   return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, day);
}
```